# Can I use Ajax and ASP.NET Tracing on the same page?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, trace

I'm using an Ajax update panel and have recently added ASP.NET tracing code to aid in debugging. All of the sudden I started getting *PageRequestManagerParseErrorExceptions* when any Ajax code is executed.

For example:
    Trace.Write("Done setting employeeId.");

Apparently this is because I am not allowed to use "server tracing" along with Ajax. (according to [this post by Eilon Lipton](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx)).

Is this true? Am I not allowed to use the awesome ASP.NET tracing mechanism? It would be a shame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting pageOutput="false" on the trace element in web.config seems to solve the problem.

Use ASP.NET tracing, but rather write to the normal diagnostics trace by setting the *writeToDiagnosticsTrace* attribute to "true" (this is on the trace element in your web.config file).